# Can I build a web page with <div> rather than <table> and still split pages in several regions?

Tags: html, css

I am making a web page that needs a header (on top) and a left aligned menu (below the header) and content to the right of that menu.

The problem I am facing is that I want to use  (with elements and floats) rather than  to create the struture of the page however, whenever I resize the browser window the content element floats down under the menu. I want the content to stick to the right of the left floating menu.

Any one got any ideas how I can fix this?

my html code has this structure:

```
 <div id="menu">
    <a href="#">menu #1</a>
    ...
    ...
    ...
 </div>
 <div id="subcontent">
    text or whatnot...
 </div>
```

Css file look like this:

```
 #menu
 {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
 }

 #subcontent
 { 
      width: 800px;
      float: left;   
 }
```

PS I have tried changing pixels to % but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an outer container.

Simply try wrapping both elements in a div of width 1000px

```
<div class="outer">
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="#">menu #1</a>   
    </div>
    <div id="subcontent">    
    </div>
</div>


.outer{width: 1000px;}
#menu
{
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

#subcontent
{ 
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 800px;
    float: left;   
}
```

Comment: `.outer{width: 1001px;}` you must add 1px to the Parent container or some browser will display the second floating DIV under the first one.

Answer (score 2):

CSS

```
#layout {
    min-width: 1001px;
}

#menu {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

#subcontent {
    width: 800px;
    float: left;
}

.clear-both {
    clear: both;
    font: 1px/1px monospace;
    display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="layout">
  <div id="menu"> <a href="#">menu #1</a> ...
    ...
    ... </div>
  <div id="subcontent"> text or whatnot... </div>
  <div class="clear-both"></div>
</div>
```

Another solution:

CSS

```
#layout {
    display: table;
    width: 1000px; /* set it to 100% if #subcontent width is dynamic */
}

#menu {
    width: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
}

#subcontent {
    width: 800px; /* you can remove the width to make it dynamic */
    display: table-cell;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="layout">
  <div id="menu"> <a href="#">menu #1</a> ...
    ...
    ... </div>
  <div id="subcontent"> text or whatnot... </div>
</div>
```